# Isn't Func<T, bool> and Predicate<T> the same thing after compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, predicate, func

Haven't fired up reflector to look at the difference but would one expect to see the exact same compiled code when comparing `Func<T, bool>`  vs. `Predicate<T>`

I would imagine there is no difference as both take a generic parameter and return bool?

Comment: @Sean - the difference lies in communicating intent. When I use a predicate, I mean to use the block of code as a 'test' and take action based on the test result. When I use a `Func<T, bool>`, I just need to mandate a function which takes a parameter and returns a bool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Func<T,bool> instead of Predicate<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665494/why-funct-bool-instead-of-predicatet)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They share the same signature, but they're still different types.

Answer (score 17):

Robert S. is completely correct; for example:-

```
class A {
  static void Main() {
    Func<int, bool> func = i => i > 100;
    Predicate<int> pred = i => i > 100;

    Test<int>(pred, 150);
    Test<int>(func, 150); // Error
  }

  static void Test<T>(Predicate<T> pred, T val) {
    Console.WriteLine(pred(val) ? "true" : "false");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The more flexible `Func` family only arrived in .NET 3.5, so it will functionally duplicate types that had to be included earlier out of necessity.

(Plus the name `Predicate` communicates the intended usage to readers of the source code)

Answer (score 0):

Even without generics, you can have different delegate types that are identical in signatures and return types. For example:

```
namespace N
{
  // Represents a method that takes in a string and checks to see
  // if this string has some predicate (i.e. meets some criteria)
  // or not.
  internal delegate bool StringPredicate(string stringToTest);

  // Represents a method that takes in a string representing a
  // yes/no or true/false value and returns the boolean value which
  // corresponds to this string
  internal delegate bool BooleanParser(string stringToConvert);
}
```

In the above example, the two non-generic types have the same signature and return type. (And actually also the same as `Predicate<string>` and `Func<string, bool>`). But as I tried to indicate, the "meaning" of the two are different.

This is somewhat like if I make two classes, `class Car { string Color; decimal Price; }` and `class Person { string FullName; decimal BodyMassIndex; }`, then just because both of them hold a `string` and a `decimal`, that doesn't mean they're the "same" type.