# Why is it impossible to cast Func<T, bool> to Predicate<T>?

Tags: c#, delegates

I found myself in a situation where I had to do some stuff with elements of a list and then remove them from that list :

```
foreach (var element in someList.Where(e => e.IsMatching))
{
    // do some stuff
}

someList.RemoveAll(e => e.IsMatching);
```

This woks perfectly but I don't like the duplicate lambda, so I declared a `Func<T, bool> x = e => e.IsMatching;` and then tried to use `x` as a parameter for `.Where` and `.RemoveAll` but I wasn't able to use `x` for `.RemoveAll` because its overload only accepts `Predicate<T>`.

Why isn't an implicit nor explicit cast possible since both have the same return and parameter types?

(I am not looking for a way to make the conversion, everything about it is already [in this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/731249/10352740))

Comment: Why don't use the solution from linked thread?

Comment: ... because the language doesn't allow implicit or explicit conversions between different delegate types (even if they have compatible signatures)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski as mentionned in the question, i'm not looking for a way to perform the conversion, i'm just asking why is the cast not possible

Comment: @canton7 Ok I kind of guessed that but why didn't the C# designers implement this?

Comment: Because there was no need? Remember that `Func` is a relatively new addition: the original intention, as far as I can gather, was that each *use* of a delegate would get its own delegate type: the name of the delegate and the names of its parameters were just as important as the *types* of the parameters. Under that, why would you be able to implicitly cast a `Predicate<T>` (which is used for determining if an object meets a criterion) to, say, a `Converter<T, bool>` (which is used for mapping between data types): they're different things entirely! Then linq came along...

Comment: If you would have two classes like `class A { int a; }` and `class B { int a; }` you would also not come up with the idea of assignability among these types.

Comment: Yeah I understand the problem now, while it could look interesting to have in some cases, it could also lead to unconsistent behaviours which is definitely not acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little silly that the `IEnumerable<T>.Where` extension method and `List<T>`'s `RemoveAll` method take two different types.  However, this is a simple work-around, since the local function can be used to initialize both a `Func<int, bool>` and a `Predicate<int>`:

```
var l = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6};
bool Pred(int i) => i < 5;
var wh = l.Where(Pred);
var rem = l.RemoveAll(Pred);
```