# Memory leak in WPF app due to DelegateCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, delegatecommand

I just finished desktop apps written in WPF and c# using MVVM pattern. In this app I used Delegate Command implementation to wrap the ICommands properties exposed in my ModelView. The problem is these DelegateCommands prevent my ModelView and View from being garbage collected after closing the view. So it stays larking until I terminate the whole application. I profile the application I find it’s all about delegatecommand that keeping the modelview in memory. 
How could I avoid this situation and is this in nature of mvvm pattern, or it’s about my implantation of the pattern?. Thanks.

Edit: this is small but complete portion of how i implement MVVM pattern

First: CommandDelegte class

```
class DelegateCommand:ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Predicate<object> canExcute;
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExcute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.canExcute != null)
        {
            return canExcute(parameter);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Second: ModelView Class

```
public class ViewModel:DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DelegateCommand printCommand;

    public ICommand PrintCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (printCommand == null)
            {
                printCommand = new DelegateCommand(Print, CanExecutePrint);
            }
            return printCommand;
        }
    }
    void Print(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print Command");

    }
    bool CanExecutePrint(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnProeprtyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Third: Window code behind

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

Forth: My XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="P" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding Path=PrintCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Print - Ctrl+P" Width="75" Height="75" Command="{Binding Path=PrintCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You should really use `Func<object, bool>` instead of `Predicate<object>` ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665494/why-funct-bool-instead-of-predicatet

Answer (score 9):

In your case, what contains a reference to what?

1. `DelegateCommand` contains a reference to `ViewModel` - its `execute` and `canExecute` properties contain references to a methods of the `ViewModel` instance.
2. `ViewModel` contains a reference to `DelegateCommand` - its `PrintCommand` property.
3. The view contains any number of references to the `ViewModel`.
4. The `CommandManager` contains a reference to `DelegateCommand` in its `RequerySuggested` event.

That last reference is a special case:  `CommandManager` uses a `WeakReference` in its `RequerySuggested` event, so despite the fact that `DelegateCommand` registers for that event, it can still be garbage-collected.

Given all this, you shouldn't be having a problem.  If the view gets disposed, neither the `ViewModel` nor the `DelegateCommand` should be reachable.

You say you've profiled the application and `DelegateCommand` is holding a reference to `ViewModel`.  It seems to me that the logical next question should be:  what's holding a reference to `DelegateCommand`? It shouldn't be `CommandManager`.  Do you have something else in your application that's referencing your commands?

Comment: @Robert Rossney: very excellent point to start with, but how about binding i do in the view to properties and commands comes from ViewModel which will subscribe to PropertyChanged event to be notified, are these will be managed by WPF framework? Is there any concern from these binding operations? Thanks..

Comment: To answer that question definitively I'd have to poke around with Reflector, but I'm reasonably certain that the binding contains references only to its source and its target, and nothing else has a reference to the binding.  So if the garbage collector can't find the view or view model from the root, the fact that they're both referencing and referenced by a binding won't affect whether or not they get garbage-collected.  But you're using a profiler:  does it tell you what's got a reference to `DelegateCommand`?

Comment: Yes, it tells me that DelegateCommand has a reference in ModelView and marked as WeakReference but they never being collected, I know that because I leave profile running for a while and take a new snapshot i find them there. Implementing IDisposible and setting all command to null in Dispose result to nothing.
Continue...

Comment: I'm not sure how to effectively release these DelegateCommand references, but I'm sure I'm missing something and any help will be appreciated as this leak annoying me because when I look at Processes tab in Windows Task Manager I see my application not release what it gets from memory but keeps growing. Thanks..

Comment: As far as I understand the CommandManager does not contain a reference to the DelegateCommand instance but to the view:

The view subscribes to the CanExecuteChanged event of the DelegateCommand (that would make the DelegateCommand contain a reference to the view) but the DelegateCommand passes that reference to the CommandManager.
Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex:  No, I don't think you're wrong.  I wasn't looking at this closely enough.  From what Abdullah has just posted, I don't think it's the CommandManager that's the source of the problem here.  DelegateCommand's not getting garbage-collected because the view model is holding a reference to it.  What's holding a reference to the view model?

Answer (score 1):

After reading this post, I then came across a web page that had some relating information. It is a page on CodePlex called [Memory Leak caused by DelegateCommand.CanExecuteChanged Event](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/4065?ProjectName=compositewpf).

Reported by : huetter
Updated by : dschenkelman

> When profiling my application I noticed that plenty of EventHandlers
>   had never   been deregistered from DelegateCommand's
>   CanExecuteChanged-Event. So those   EventHandlers were never been
>   garbage-collector, which caused a severe memory   leak.
>
> As registering CanExecuteChanged-EventHandles is done outside
>   application code   scope I had expected them to be deregistered
>   automatically as well. At this   point I thought this might as well be
>   a ThirdParty WPF control issue, but   digging further I read a blog
>   post stating that "WPF expects the   ICommand.CanExecuteChanged-Event
>   to apply WeakReferences for EventHandlers". I   had a look into
>   RoutedCommand, and noticed it uses WeakReferences as well.
>
> I adapted DelegateCommand to use an implementation similar to
>   RoutedCommand's   CanExecuteChanged-Event, and the memory leak was
>   gone. The same is true for   CompositeCommand.
>
> Closed Nov 3, 2009 at 6:28 PM by      This issue was fixed in the
>   Prism-v2.1 release, so the Workitem is closed now.   Prism 2.1 can be
>   downloaded from here:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=387c7a59-b217-4318-ad1b-cbc2ea453f40&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this code there is a circular reference which is causing the ViewModel to never be garbage collected.

I know this is an old question, but I will point out that some implementations of DelegateCommand or [RelayCommand](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Command/RelayCommand.cs) hold a WeakReference to the action. Your use of the DelegateCommand here is typical, but unfortunately will cause memory leaks with this implementation because when the ViewModel's method is passed into the DelegateCommand's constructor, a reference to the class containing that method is automatically captured by the delegate.

If you implemented IDispose on your ViewModel and cleared the references to the DelegateCommands explicitly in Dispose, then you could continue to use this implementation. Your view that's constructing your ViewModel would also have to Dipose of it, however.

Comment: The problem here is not `DelegateCommand` preventing `ViewModel` from being garbage collected, but that something (maybe `WPF Control` or `ViewModel` preventing `DelegateCommand` from being garbage collected).

Comment: Yes, which is why adding Dispose to the ViewModel, to allow the ViewModel to get rid of it's reference to DelegateCommand might help. There is definitely a circular reference here between the DelegateCommand and the ViewModel, but whether either of those are rooted and preventing garbage collection I don't know.