# Unsubscribing from CommandManager.RequerySuggested? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Im implementing a simple `Button` in WPF, that is bound in XAML to an `ICommand`.

Whilst it works great, I've got it triggering `CanExecute()` via the following code:

```
 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
```

The problem is, the instantiated `ICommand` is being kept alive by this event, and even after I've finished with it, `CanExecute()` is continually triggered by the `CommandManager`.

I supposed I've got a temporary undesirable fix in the form of a `List<EventHandler>` inside the `ICommand` instance, that adds each incoming `value` from the `add{}` , which i'm then manually unsubscribing from by just iterating it and calling `CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= eventItem`, but I'm wondering if there is a better way or i'm using it wrongly?

Comment: Please read here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3047677/1979354

Comment: That seems to indicate it should be garbage collected, but then a load of users report that it isn't, and `CanExecute` is still being called - which i'm also facing...

Comment: Did you check it on release without debugger?

Comment: Argh, so it works correctly without the debugger, but this is not good enough unfortunately :(.

Comment: Why this is not good? Debugger is pretty great feature of Studio, but, yes, it works little strange with disposing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs&list=PLcJBKdjm-X2QuY5CxC75TftE_Rfwi3BAP&index=2&t=710s