# Method with Predicate as Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects, predicate

This is a general question, but here is the specific case I'm looking for a solution to:

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` I want to apply various predicates to. I want one method that can take care of multiple LINQ queries such as these:

```
from x in Dictionary
where x.Value.Contains("Test")
select x.Key

from x in Dictionary
where x.Value.Contains("Test2")
select x.Key
```

So I'm looking for a method like so:

```
public int GetResult(**WhatGoesHere** filter)
{
    return from x in Dictionary.Where(filter)
           select x.Key;
}
```

To be used like so:

```
int result;

result = GetResult(x => x.Value.Contains("Test"));
result = GetResult(x => x.Value.Contains("Test2"));
```

What is the proper syntax for **WhatGoesHere**?

Comment: Woops, I missed the right type. I deleted my answer. Mark Byer's answer is good.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Func<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>, bool>`:

```
public int GetResult(Func<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>, bool> filter)
{
    return (from x in Dictionary
            where filter(x)
            select x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or alternatively: `Predicate<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>`. I think `Func` which was introduced in .NET 3.5 is [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665494/c-why-funct-bool-instead-of-predicatet) these days.

You are using `x` to mean two different things in your final example and this will give a compile error. Try changing one of the `x`s to something else:

```
x = GetResult(y => y.Value.Contains("Test1"));
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I was on the right path. I was doing Predicate<Dictionary<int, List<string>>> but I guess that wouldn't make much sense. Thanks.