# Advantage of Predicate<T> over Func<T,bool>?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Is there any value to using a predicate over a normal delegate? Taking the example below, I don't see any.

```
Predicate<int> isEven = delegate(int x) { return x % 2 == 0; };
Console.WriteLine(isEven(1) + "\r\r");

Func<int, bool> isEven2 = delegate(int x) { return x % 2 == 0; };
Console.WriteLine(isEven(1) + "\r\r");
```

Comment: isn't it the other way around? related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/665494/17447

Answer (score 7):

They're effectively the same. `Predicate<T>` is a delegate type that was added to the base class library for list and array *Find()* methods. This was before LINQ, which was when the more general `Func` family of delegates were introduced. You could even write your own delegate type and use that:

```
delegate bool IntPredicate(int x); 

static void Main()
{
   IntPredicate isEven = delegate(int x) {return x % 2 == 0;};
   Console.WriteLine(isEven(1) + "\r\r");
}
```

Comment: +1, though I am often torn too between the rather ugly looking (but generalized) `Func<T,bool>` and the nicer looking `Predicate<T>`. Especially considering Func says nothing about its intended usage whereas Predicate sorta does.

Comment: I hardly ever have to specify the delegate type as I just enter them as type-inferenced lambdas, e.g., `foo( x => x % 2 == 0);`

Comment: With `Predicate<T>`, the intended usage of the delegate is more explicit.  Then again, if you do a good job of naming the parameter, the difference might be negligible.  E.g. `public SomeObj Find(Func<SomeObj, bool> isMatch) { }` vs `public SomeObj Find(Predicate<SomeObj> isMatch) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

Predicate is a delegate. It is a delegate defined in the .Net framework 3.0. Predicate always returns a boolean value. So both delegates in your code are equivalent. Other delegates provided by .Net are Func and Action. Action returns void.

Comment: Actually, it is available starting in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Only that a bunch of the Microsoft-provided library code uses it.

For example: [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) needs to be passed a `Predicate`.

For your own code, you can use whichever one you like.  You could even use `Converter<int, bool>`.

Answer (score 0):

They're effectively the same. That said, extension methods (in your personal library or someone else's) are more likely to be defined on `Func<T, TResult>` so I'd prefer that one.

Answer (score 0):

For consistency with LINQ I tend to define `Func<T, bool>` over `Predicate<T>`.