# Value extractor for Predicates

Tags: java, function, java-8, predicate

In Java 8, the `Comparator` class has this [really nifty static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) that composes a `Function` to a `Comparator` by using the the result of the `Function` as the input for the `Comparator`.

What I would like to do, is be able to compose `Function` objects with other types like `Predicate`, in order to make my code more readable, and to make my functional operations more powerful.

For example, say there is a `Set<Person>` where `Person` has a `public String getName()` method. I want to be able to filter out the `Person` objects that don't have a name. Ideally, the syntax would look like this:

```
people.removeIf(Predicates.andThenTest(Person::getName, String::isEmpty));
```

*Are there any built-in methods that can compose a `Function` with something like a `Predicate`?* I'm aware of [`Function#andThen(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-), but that is only useful for combining functions with other functions, and sadly, `Predicate` doesn't `extend Function<T, Boolean>`.

P.S. I'm also aware that I could use a lambda like `p -> p.getName().isEmpty()`, but I would like for a way to compose pre-existing `Predicate` objects with a `Function`.

Comment: Given the responses to [How to negate a method reference predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate?rq=1), I'm thinking my question is probably in a family of questions which wish `Predicate` was implemented better. Hopefully it will be improved in the future :)

Comment: Given how long lambda has been developed before made it to jdk eventually, I am thinking whether the reason of `Predicate` and `Function` being in the language [is the same as in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/665513/1026104)

Comment: There are so many possible functional combinations that it is pointless to ask why a particular combination has been provided and another hasn’t. All you need to now is that there is none and you can create your own, which has no drawbacks compared to a hypothetical JRE provided solution.

Comment: @Holger I agree. Part of my reason for bringing this up is that I see that this is a very common operation in SO questions which usually can't be solved without a lambda. I'm one of those guys who prefers not to use a lambda where possible (kind of like striving for point-free notation in Haskell, I like my Streams free of lambdas where possible)

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid the `t -> pred.test(func.apply(t))` lambda expression at all costs, you can write `func.andThen(pred::test)::apply` instead. But really, there are places, where you should accept a lambda expression. After all, that’s what the JRE provided factory would use internally too.

Comment: I've moved my workaround method to the answers, so that the Q&A format still fits. Future readers may find it helpful to see the check mark so that they don't have to read all of the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a value extractor method for predicates built into Java 8, but the next best solution is to implement it yourself:

```
public class Predicates {
    public static <T,R> Predicate<T> andThenTest(
            Function<T,R> func, Predicate<R> pred) {
        return t -> pred.test(func.apply(t));
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Holger, that could also be:

```
return func.andThen(pred::test)::apply;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make cast a `Predicate` as a `Function` like this:

```
Predicate<String> p = String::isEmpty;
Function<String, Boolean> g = p::test; // predicate to function
Function<Boolean, String> f = Object::toString;
f.compose(g); // or g.andThen(f);
```

Comment: Sweet! But then for me to use it on a function that takes a predicate, I need to cast that composed `Function` back to a `Predicate`. @Holger used `::apply` to do that. It's fairly awkward to read, which makes me hesitant, but it certainly can work in a pinch! I think I'll stick with my static method for now.